# How to destroy the Activity on switching other Activity in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I have 3 activity I want to destroy the earlier activity when i move to new activity in TabActivity

```
TabHosttabHost = getTabHost();


    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    // adding each tab details to tabhost
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("1")
            .setIndicator("TAB3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1))
            .setContent(it5));
                    Intent it5 = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    // adding each tab details to tabhost
    Intent in2 = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("2")
            .setIndicator("TAB3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2))
            .setContent(it5));
                    Intent it5 = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    // adding each tab details to tabhost
    Intent in3 = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("3")
            .setIndicator("TAB3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3))
            .setContent(it5));
```

Comment: In one activity all the tab activity shall be running on load of tab all activity shall be active

Comment: can i ask 'why you want this behavior'?

Comment: @dd619 I want to  destroy all the object created in the activity bcoz it is of no more use it is just eating the heap memory

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Tab Activity then(TabActivity is deprecated now).

Simply create three activities and place three buttons at the bottom of each activity.

and while switching from one activity to another just call `finish()` after `startActivity()`.

I am again saying not to use TabActivity because i have used it in one of my project an that was a headache for me.

Comment: upvoted for headache for me. I am easily running out of memory for using TabActivity